# Elastic Search facet counts don't add up to total hits

Tags: elasticsearch

Please see my gist for the full details: https://gist.github.com/jenkoian/85a3f69fcbf88a87538e

Most of the searching I've done on this has brought me back to https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1305 so I tried putting my index on a single shard and I get the same issue with incorrect counts.

Comment: Ok, my example here was a whittled down version of what I thought was the issue. The actual issue I had was to do with facet counts not quite matching the total hits. I discovered that it was expected behaviour because of some results existing in multiple facets.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify `search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch` ?
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html